# What chromedriver version download If I have chrome 114.0.5735.110?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded chromedriver 114.0.5735.90 but I got the error:

I am using chrome 114.0.5735.110 but I can't find this verion of chromedriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\ola12\PycharmProjects\spam\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 42, in get_path
   path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
 File "C:\Users\ola12\PycharmProjects\spam\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 74, in driver_location
   browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from settings import settings

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ola12/Desktop/chrom/chromedriver.exe')


def login_form():  # Open website and login
    driver.get(settings['url'])


login_form()
```

Comment: Try like this: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ola12\Desktop\chrom\chromedriver.exe")

Answer (score 0):

Instructions = https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_114 or https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE.  Both return version 114.0.5735.90 which was reported in his original post.  I also had issues using the .90 driver with the .134 build of Chrome.  I rolled my Chrome version back to .90 and it is now working for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try follow theses steps to find your chrome version: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection
After you find your chrome version you can go to this page:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Download your the right version and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).